# How to pass Formik's field prop to a storybook story

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook, storybook-addon

I'm trying to create a story for one of my components that use Formik. Here's the component:

```
import { memo } from 'react';

import { OutlinedTextFieldProps } from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { InputAdornment, TextField as MuiTextField } from '@mui/material';
import { FieldProps } from 'formik';

interface TextFieldPropsInterface extends OutlinedTextFieldProps, FieldProps {
  validationErrors?: Record<string, string[]> | undefined;
  loading?: boolean;
  endAdornmentText?: string;
}

function TextField({
  loading,
  validationErrors,
  field,
  form,
  endAdornmentText,
  ...TextFieldProps
}: TextFieldPropsInterface) {
  const { name } = field;
  const { touched, errors } = form;
  const { helperText } = TextFieldProps;

  const hasError = touched[name] && Boolean(errors[name]);
  const errorMessage = errors && errors[name];

  return (
    <MuiTextField
      {...TextFieldProps}
      error={hasError}
      helperText={hasError ? errorMessage : helperText}
      disabled={loading || TextFieldProps?.disabled}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: endAdornmentText ? (
          <InputAdornment position='end'>{endAdornmentText}</InputAdornment>
        ) : null,
      }}
      {...field}
    />
  );
}

export default memo(TextField);
```

Here's my story for this component:

```
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta, storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { withFormik } from '@bbbtech/storybook-formik';

import FormikTextField from '.';

export default {
  component: FormikTextField,
  decorators: [withFormik],
} as unknown as ComponentMeta<typeof FormikTextField>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof FormikTextField> = (args) => (
  <FormikTextField {...args} />
);

export const Default = Template.bind({});

Default.args = {
  loading: false,
  validationErrors: undefined,
  endAdornmentText: 'End adornment',
};
```

This is throwing an error:

```
TypeError
Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'field' as it is undefined.
Call Stack
 TextField
  main.iframe.bundle.js:1497:5
 renderWithHooks
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:116439:18
 mountIndeterminateComponent
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:119265:13
 beginWork
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:120503:16
 HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:105399:14
 Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:105448:16
 invokeGuardedCallback
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:105510:31
 beginWork$1
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:125413:7
 performUnitOfWork
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:124225:12
 workLoopSync
  vendors-node_modules_bbbtech_storybook-formik_dist_esm_index_js-node_modules_mui_icons-materi-41c387.iframe.bundle.js:124156:5
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its still relevant, but I noticed 2 things in your code.

1. when you use withFormik addon, you need to specify initial value of the input for the formik,  so since you use MuiTextfield you should have there name (fo example lastname) and then you add into your story this

> ```
> Default.parameters = {
>     formik: {
>         initialValues: {
>             lastname: '',
>         },
>     },
> };
> ```

2. you dont control value of your MuiTextfield, not sure if it is intended or you just missed it, but I usually control the value.

hope it helps